# How to convert some columns to JSON Child elements in u-sql?

Tags: json, azure, u-sql

I am working on **u-sql queries** which convert the data into JSON object.
But in some scenarios I have make some columns as Child JSON elements for some Employees,

> I am having the Addresses data in Address,City and Zipcode Columns for two Employees as below,

[image]

> I have to output every Employee Address data as **JSON child** element in the following format,

```
"Addresses": [
     {
      "Address": "1st Street",
      "City": "NY",
      "ZipCode": "96826"
     },
     {
      "Address": "2st Street",
      "City": "CA",
      "ZipCode": "45896"
     }
],
```

> **Note1:**
>   I have used the default JSON Outputter which outputs all the columns for Single Employee as JSON, but I want to output the Addresses for every Employee in above order.
>
> **Note2:**
>   I had even tried to make the Child element as string using ARRAY_AGG and MAP_AGG but nothing worked for me.

**Reference:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt763803.aspx

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own JSON outputter that knows how to nest the data.

For example, create the rowset in a way that it has a `SqlArray<SqlMap<string,string>>` that contains the Address elements as `SqlMap`s and then write an outputter that maps the construct into a nested JSON object.